# Как выровнять текст по центру в slick slider?

Tags: slick.js

Вопрос по slick слайдеру. По дизайну слайды должны быть в виде фотографий, по центру которых расположен текст. Изначально я в разметке я создала блок p с текстом, задала ему `padding-top` и bottom в процентах, родителю `text-align`: center и установила картинку, как background. Проблема в том, что текст разной длины, и если на большом экране на всех слайдах он помещается в одну строку, то на экранах поменьше на одном из слайдов он расположен в 2 строки, а на другом в 3 строки. Из-за этого паддинги становятся разными и при прокрутке слайдера появляются внизу пустые полосы, так как скачет высота самих слайдов. Как можно решить эту проблему? Я пыталась переделать структуру слайдов, задавала картинку через тег `img`, а текст позиционировала абсолютно, но в таком случае не получается выровнять его по центру, так как ширина экрана все время меняется.

```
 <section class="features">
        <div class="features__slider">
            <div class="js__slider">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center test">
                        <p class="features__promo features__promo_fast">ПОИСК НЕОБХОДИМОЙ ИФОРМАЦИИ В БАЗЕ ЗАНИМАЕТ МЕНЬШЕ МИНУТЫ</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="js__slider">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center test">
                        <p class="features__promo features__promo_true">ТОЛЬКО ДОСТОВЕРНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ,СОБРАННЫЕ ИЗ ОФИЦИАЛЬНОЙ ТЕХНИЧЕСКОЙ ДОКУМЕНТАЦИИ</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="js__slider">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center test">
                        <p class="features__promo features__promo_online">ИНТУТИВНО-ПОНЯТНЫЙ ИНТЕРФЕЙС И ДОСТУПНОСТЬ ОНЛАЙН В ЛЮБОЕ ВРЕМЯ</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>


.features
&__promo
    padding-top: 24%
    padding-bottom: 19%
    margin-bottom: 0
    background-image: url("../img/slide__1-1.jpg")
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    font-size: 20px
    @extend %open__bold
    color: $white
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
        font-size: 16px
    @media screen and (max-width: 576px)
        font-size: 14px
    &_true
        background-image: url("../img/slide__2-5.jpg")
    &_online
        background-image: url("../img/slide__2-2.jpg")
.js-slider

    max-width: 1908px
```

Comment: попробуйте задать паддинги в пикселях, в процентах получаются большие отступы

Answer (score 0):

Использовать flex верстку

```
.text-center{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
.text-center p{
    text-align: center;
}
```